# How to end C Shell Script when calling continues process

Tags: java, shell, process, aix, csh

### Ok, I apologize. Been playing around with the process by killing it and starting it and it looks like I am not ending the script properly.

I have a `csh` script that I run to start a java application on an AIX system.

**What I normally do:**

In a typescript/terminal I run

`startApp.csh >> ../log/app.log &`

But I am running into an issue where the `startApp.csh` will not stop after java app starts up. It shows up in the background like:
`/bin/csh startApp.csh`
along side the java process `$JRE_HOME/bin/java -XMS16M -Xmx512M \-Set \-all \-necessary \-environments $argv[*]`. They are both now dependent on each other to keep running. If I kill the `/bin/csh startApp.csh` the java application wont stop with my port calls, unless I do a`kill -9`

*startApp.csh*

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv JAR_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JAVA_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JRE_HOME /to/directory/
set CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:$to/path"
$JRE_HOME/bin/java -XMS16M -Xmx512M \-Set \-all \-necessary \-environments $argv[*]
```

I dont know how to tell my script to end when java application runs. How can I achieve that?

---

An Update:

This is what I have tried so far to have the java child process run on its own and for the parent shell-script to die.

In a typescript/terminal I run

`startApp.csh >> ../log/app.log`

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv JAR_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JAVA_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JRE_HOME /to/directory/
set CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:$to/path"
nohup $JRE_HOME/bin/java ... $argv[*] &
```

The `nohup command &` will ignore the fact that the parent has ended and will take me back to my typescript/terminal for next input.

I just dont know enough if it matters that the process runs as a child with a PPID of 1.

Comment: Do I correctly gather that you aren't actually showing us the csh script which is misbehaving here?

Comment: BTW, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` keyword (it's mentioned in more than one context -- the first table is "syntax tolerated by bash with few if any legitimate uses"; the third is "features that are used only if you have a specific reason to prefer it over an alternative").

Comment: Also, your excerpt from `maintenance.bash` shows only a function definition.  The context and specifics of the relevant function *call* are at least as important.

Comment: Please test that what's provided here is a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code *complete enough to reproduce the problem in question* when run on its own.

Comment: Show us, don't just tell us. Anything you do in that code that spawns a subshell or sets something to happen after the java code finishes is our answer. Right now, we have nothing but your word to go off of -- but if you knew everything that your scripts were doing, you wouldn't have a question in the first place.

Comment: I don't see any typescript code here.

Comment: The shell script *will* hang around until its children have finished. You will find the same holds for your Bash scripts. Perhaps you are just baffled by this simple fact?

Comment: The startApp.csh script is being forked so I would assume startup.bash would end when that happens...? This why I forked since the java application will continually run and would hang the bash script.. I get that

Comment: I updated the post.. hope that helps.

Comment: ...so, your csh script is running a command in the foreground. A shell *can* implicitly `exec` the last external command it invokes, but there's no obligation for it to do so -- and if it isn't implemented to have that particular optimization, it needs to `wait()` for that program to exit so it can then itself exit with the same status.

Comment: That said, it would be considerably less messy (and provide you a lot of benefits, such as the ability to enable automatic restart on failure) to switch away from this mess of scripts to a proper process supervision system -- systemd, DJB daemontools, upstart, runit, etc.

Comment: (Also, when you say "dead process", that typically means Z-state -- zombied, having exited but not left the process table; here, it sounds like what you have is just an *idle* process, sitting in a `wait()` call doing nothing until its child exits).

Comment: You're saying zombie -- if that's the case, it suggests a very specific line of investigation: Who's the parent in the process table if you look with `pstree`? That's the process that's supposed to be responsible for calling `waitpid()` or another `wait`-family call to reap the zombie from the process table. Pasting the output of the relevant snippet from `ps auxw --forest` (if on a platform supporting it) is liable to be helpful.

Comment: To answer the original question: `csh` does have `exec` command.

Comment: How is that used and how does it behave?

Comment: `exec $JRE_HOME/bin/java ... $argv:q` the shell-script terminates when it starts the program.

Comment: What if the startApp.csh (which is the script that starts the java program) is a child, what happens to the parent if it still has more processes to do?

Comment: In your original post you used an &ampersand at the end of the command (`startApp.csh >> ../log/app.log &`) so it won't wait for the java-application to terminate. A note: you could use `nohup` in this context: `nohup ./startApp.csh >>../log/app.log &`

Comment: Thank you this seems to work perfectly. Instead I used it like this `nohup java sever app &`. It keeps the application in the background and prevents it from quitting when I log out. Also the startApp.csh quits when it forks off

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use `exec`:

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv JAR_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JAVA_HOME /to/directory/
setenv JRE_HOME /to/directory/
set CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:$to/path"
exec $JRE_HOME/bin/java -XMS16M -Xmx512M \-Set \-all \-necessary \-environments $argv[*]
```

Without `exec` the csh assumes that it needs to stick around as a process and will wait for the java process to end, it will then execute the next line in the csh script. In your case there is no next line, so it ends.

With `exec` the csh process is ''replaced'' with the Java process, with the same process id.